# jQuery stop loop at first match?

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty new with jQuery, and I was wonder if it is possible to stop a .each loop after the first match.

This is my code so far:

```
(function() {
  var result;
  result = null;
  this.model.each(function(model, index, collection) {
    var mode;
    mode = model.get("Mode");
    if (mode === Zone.Mode) {
      return result = model.id;
    }
  });
  console.debug("Room = " + result);
  return result;
});
```

and obviously it returns the last match of the loop.

What I need is to return the first element, and this is what I tried:

```
(function() {
  var result;
  result = null;
  this.model.each(function(model, index, collection) {
    var mode;
    mode = model.get("Mode");
    if (mode === Zone.Mode & (result = null)) {
      return result = model.id;
    }
  });
  console.debug("Room = " + result);
  return result;
});
```

basically i've added to the if statement `& (result = null)`, but the console returns `'Room = null'`

any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: (result = null) check with == equal to

Comment: two things to change in condition:
if (mode === Zone.Mode && (result == null))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return result = model.id`; will return the result of the assignment, which will be model.id and therefore not false, so won't break out of the loop - you don't want this, you want to return false to break out of the loop - [freedomn-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181514/freedomn-m)

Store the result and the return

```
if (mode === Zone.Mode) {
  result = model.id;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: As an explanation: `return result = model.id;` will return the result of the assignment, which will be model.id and therefore not false, so won't break out of the loop - you don't want this, you want to return false to break out of the loop.